# Schedule regular event workers

Tags: scheduling, human-resources, job-scheduler

I am responsible to plan the schedules for the workers that have to work on sports events and I am searching for a program to help me. The constraints are as follows:

- Each event must have 2 workers
- At season start, I would like to insert all events
- Each worker can go, see list of matches and say if he could or not work here (a little bit like Doodle)
- Once everybody said their preference, I (or the software) can assign each event to 2 workers, trying to not assign all events to the same people.

Ideally, it should be web or mobile app (Android and iOS).

I have ~50 events / season and 10-15 workers.